# UITableView - Multiple and Single selection in different sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with 2 different sections. Is it posible to have multiple selection in one section and single selection in the other? If I use:

```
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
```

it affects the whole table.

Answer (score 4):

I'll expose my own solution, that is pretty much the same one as the one you posted. I think it's a tad better though, since I manually manage the selected rows so I can use the `tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows` property later on.

It's written in Swift 2.

### Solution

I first declare a NSIndexPath that will store the previously selected item

```
var indexPathOfPreviouslySelectedRow: NSIndexPath?
```

I then use these tableView delegate functions (my single selection section is 0, my multiple selection is 1)

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        if let previousIndexPath = indexPathOfSelectedRowPaidBy {
            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(previousIndexPath, animated: false)
            tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(previousIndexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
        }
        indexPathOfSelectedRowPaidBy = indexPath
        tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark

    case 1:
        tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark

    default:
        break
    }


}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        if let previousIndexPath = indexPathOfSelectedRowPaidBy {
            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(previousIndexPath, animated: false)
            tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(previousIndexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
        }
        indexPathOfSelectedRowPaidBy = nil

    case 1:
        tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None

    default:
        break
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll expose my own solution, that is pretty much the same one as the one you posted. I think it's a tad better though, since I manually manage the selected rows so I can use the tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows property later on.

It's written in Swift 3.0.

I first declare a NSIndexPath that will store the previously selected item

var indexPathOfSelectedRowPaidBy: NSIndexPath?

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

```
    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        if let previousIndexPath = indexPathOfSelectedRowPaidBy {
            tableView.deselectRow(at: previousIndexPath as IndexPath, animated: false)
            tableView.cellForRow(at: previousIndexPath as IndexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
        }
        indexPathOfSelectedRowPaidBy = indexPath as NSIndexPath?
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark

    case 1:
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark

    default:
        break
    }
```

}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

```
switch indexPath.section {
case 0:
    if let previousIndexPath = indexPathOfSelectedRowPaidBy {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: previousIndexPath as IndexPath, animated: false)
        tableView.cellForRow(at: previousIndexPath as IndexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
    }
    indexPathOfSelectedRowPaidBy = nil

case 1:
    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none

default:
    break
}
```

}

Comment: how to do when three section header there??

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to manage your single-selection section by implementing `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

If a different single-section row is currently selected, you can deselect it before the new single-section row is selected.

This will preserve the illusion of single selection in one section, while allowing multiple selection in the other section.

Comment: Thanks @PetahChristian!! The method worked just fine, i'll submit the way i solved it in case someone finds it useful

Answer (score 1):

This solution appears to work ok! I use a dictionary to handle the single selection, keeping record of the last index used with the section number as the key

```
    - (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        // SINGLE SELECTION - SECTIONS 0 and 2
    if( indexPath.section == 0 || indexPath.section == 2 ){
        if( cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone ){
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

            if(indexDict.count ==0){
                NSNumber *sec = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.section];
                [indexDict setObject:indexPath forKey:sec];
            }
            else{
                NSNumber *sec = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.section];
                NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath = indexDict[sec];

                UITableViewCell *lastCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath];
                lastCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

                [indexDict removeObjectForKey:sec];
                [indexDict setObject:indexPath forKey:sec];
            }
        }
        else{
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
    }
        // MULTIPLE SELECION - SECTION 1
    if( indexPath.section == 1 ){
        if( cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone ){
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        }
        else{
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath?
{
    // Allow only 1 selected row in a section #0.
    let singleSelectionSection = 0
    if indexPath.section == singleSelectionSection, let index = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows?.filter({ $0.section == singleSelectionSection }).first {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: index, animated: false)
    }

    return indexPath
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In table view same methods

> collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
>
> in section with indexPath.section == 1 will be single selection

```
var lastIndexPath: IndexPath? // store previous index path 

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

            if indexPath.section != 1 {return}

            guard lastIndexPath != nil else {lastIndexPath = indexPath; return}

            if lastIndexPath != indexPath{
                collectionView.deselectItem(at: lastIndexPath!, animated: true)
            }
            lastIndexPath = indexPath
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest and best way to do it SWIFT 5 :

```
var indexPathOfPreviouslySelectedRow: IndexPath?
```

Code below in tableview

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    if (indexPath.section == 1){
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
           print("test")
            if (indexPathOfPreviouslySelectedRow != nil ){
                tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPathOfPreviouslySelectedRow!, animated: true)
            }
            indexPathOfPreviouslySelectedRow = indexPath
        }
        if (indexPath.row == 1) {
           print("test")
            if (indexPathOfPreviouslySelectedRow != nil ){
                tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPathOfPreviouslySelectedRow!, animated: true)
            }
            indexPathOfPreviouslySelectedRow = indexPath
        }
    }
    self.footerButton.isEnabled = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow != nil
}
```