# swift4 uitableview retain selection

Tags: uitableview, swift4, didselectrowatindexpath

I am preparing a small app for online exams for which I need to reload the tableView for every question. Multiple selection and single selection both are needed based on question type. I was able to manage the selection type based on question type but the thing is when i reload the tableview the previous selection is replicating in the next question.

```
var DictItemSerialNumber = 0
let Dict = [["Question":"How many days in a week?",
             "Options":["1","2","3","7"],
             "QuestionType":1],
            ["Question":"How many days in a month?",
             "Options":["28","29","30","31","32"],
             "QuestionType":2],
            ["Question":"How many days in a Year?",
             "Options":["234","265","365","400"],
             "QuestionType":1]]
var SavedOptions = [String:[Any]]()
var selectedIndex:Int? = nil
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.Tab.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    self.Tab.estimatedRowHeight = 300
    self.Tab.tableFooterView = UIView()
    self.Tab.delegate = self
    self.Tab.dataSource = self
    self.Tab.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}
@IBAction func PrvsBtnActn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if DictItemSerialNumber > 0 {
        DictItemSerialNumber -= 1
        Tab.reloadData()
    }
}
@IBAction func NextBtnActn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if DictItemSerialNumber < Dict.count-1{
        DictItemSerialNumber += 1
        Tab.reloadData()
    }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let DictObj = Dict[DictItemSerialNumber] as NSDictionary
    let optionsCount = DictObj["Options"] as! NSArray
    return optionsCount.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = Tab.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!

    let DictObj = Dict[DictItemSerialNumber]
    let qstnType = DictObj["QuestionType"] as! Int
    if qstnType == 2{
        self.Tab.allowsMultipleSelection = true
    }else{
        self.Tab.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    }
    QstnLbl.text = DictObj["Question"] as? String
    let optionsAns = DictObj["Options"] as! NSArray
    cell.textLabel?.text = optionsAns[indexPath.row] as? String
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
        cell.accessoryType = .none
    }
}
```

}

> question type = 1 means single selection and 2 is multiple selection

Comment: Hope this example will help you. [Multiple Selection of Table View sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31860553/uitableview-multiple-and-single-selection-in-different-sections)

Comment: In code, SavedOptions Array seems not used. In didSelect method, you have to save the answer option and  in cellForRow method you can assign cell.accessoryType accordingly.